# Proxy protocol v2 for http and https in Go

Tags: go, proxy

I'm trying use AWS network ELB with proxy protocol (v2) to terminate the SSL on my server. I know that the ELB will inject the (binary) protocol information into the data stream at the beginning of the connection. I understand that I have to parse it and remove it from the stream. I'm trying to do this in Go and have no idea where do begin.

Does Go http package have any built in support for manipulating the raw data stream?

Comment: You can always manipulate the raw data stream from your own listener. An example package that does this is here: https://github.com/armon/go-proxyproto